# Differences between the OpenVPN SHA1 variations in the digest aglorithms

Tags: hash, openssl, sha, openvpn, algorithm

OpenVPN offers the use of various digest algorithms (see list below).
I've read that the the digests, printed with a leading `RSA-`, `DSA-` or `ecdsa-with-` are simply due to a print function in OpenSSL and do not affect the algorithm mentioned afterwards (e.g. RSA-SHA, DSA-SHA and SHA, are all the same and can be equally used).

What I do not understand are the differences between the SHA1 digests `SHA`, `SHA1`, `DSA-SHA1-old` and `RSA-SHA1-2`. All share the same 160 bit digest size.

Complete list of `--show-digests`:

```
MD5 128 bit digest size
RSA-MD5 128 bit digest size
SHA 160 bit digest size
RSA-SHA 160 bit digest size
SHA1 160 bit digest size
RSA-SHA1 160 bit digest size
DSA-SHA 160 bit digest size
DSA-SHA1-old 160 bit digest size
DSA-SHA1 160 bit digest size
RSA-SHA1-2 160 bit digest size
DSA 160 bit digest size
RIPEMD160 160 bit digest size
RSA-RIPEMD160 160 bit digest size
MD4 128 bit digest size
RSA-MD4 128 bit digest size
ecdsa-with-SHA1 160 bit digest size
RSA-SHA256 256 bit digest size
RSA-SHA384 384 bit digest size
RSA-SHA512 512 bit digest size
RSA-SHA224 224 bit digest size
SHA256 256 bit digest size
SHA384 384 bit digest size
SHA512 512 bit digest size
SHA224 224 bit digest size
whirlpool 512 bit digest size
```

With OpenVPN 2.4.0 and OpenSSL 1.0.2k

Is this again an odd way of OpenSSL printing digests and they all simply represent SHA1?

*edit:* Interestingly, there's no plain `SHA` nor a `DSA-SHA1-old`, when you `openssl list -digest-algorithms`.

Comment: The DSA- and RSA- refer to the digital signature algorithm and the RSA cryptographic algorithm respectively. They are signed digests. I don't know what the -old or -2 mean, though. Similarly I don't understand why there is SHA and SHA1 (probably for legacy reasons...?).

Comment: I realised that the `RSA-` algorithms just map to the corresponding algorithm without `RSA-` (see `openssl list -digest-algorithms`), but there's no mention of `DSA` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason they have the same digest size is because the same message digest algorithm is used.
The difference is what is being 'digested'.

- SHA and SHA1 are likely equivalent, and both should provide a 'normal' SHA1 hash (i.e. something you could potentially replicate by running `sha1sum INPUT`)
- DSA-SHA1-old and RSA-SHA1-2 are used for digitally signed digests - the details aren't necessarily relevant here, but basically, this avoids a MITM being able to just replace a payload + digest with something arbitrary (because a key is involved, the MITM would need to know that key to generate a valid signature for a given piece of data).